# How do I make iText 7 diacritic mark stacking work correctly?

Tags: pdf, text, formatting, itext7

I have run into a problem with `iText 7` where diacritic marks are painted on top of one another instead of stacking properly when multiple marks are used on a single character. Is there a setting that makes them appear correctly, or is this a bug in `iText 7`? Any help greatly appreciated. This can be observed if you create a text object in your PDF like below. Obviously, replace the relevant bit with an actual font object, rather than than what I have in there.

```
new Text("ḗ and ṓ are characters that display incorrectly").setFont(<UNICODE COMPATIBLE FONT LIKE CHARIS>);
```

Comment: What are the actual Unicode codes that you are writing?

Comment: The character "ḗ" is actually three unicode characters, with the respective hex values: 0x65 (e), 0x304 ( ̄ , the combining macron), and 0x301 ( ́, the combining accute accent).

Comment: Are you using the [pdfCalligraph](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) add on? If not, it's not supposed to work. All advanced typography is done by the add on.

Comment: Do you know if that module is available under the AGPL license? I appreciate the heads up that pdfCalligraph is what I'm missing!

Comment: Sorry to say that pdfCalligraph (1) is not open source and requires a (paid) license key, and (2) it won't solve your problem. I just tested and we currently don't support diacritic stacking in Latin text - honestly, because we didn't think there would be a lot of user demand for it.
FYI I am an iText employee

Comment: @blagae Thank you for the time you've taken to respond here! Do you know whether this bug will be fixed? My program is used within the ConLang community, and as such, people tend to use diacritic marks to help construct their scripts.

Comment: Technically, it's not a bug but a missing feature :-)
I have added it to the backlog and we'll investigate this, but I can't commit to a timing (or even a promise) for resolution. The warning about the pdfCalligraph module not being free will still apply if this feature is added.

Comment: @blagae Is there any way I could contact you about getting a partial license for just this, or working out a deal for it? I can show you the software that I make, which is essentially a dev kit for people working on creative projects, and completely free.

Comment: I'm not in the habit of luring in customers via SO, but you can always send an e-mail to community@itextpdf.com to open up a conversation.

Answer (score 2):

While Bruno and Benoit correctly pointed out that for advanced typography stuff like stacking diacritical marks you need `pdfCalligraph` module, there is a workaround you can try at your own risk. If your combinations of base glyph and diacritics are real, meaning they occur in real texts in some languages or some other known contexts, then such combinations are most probably present in `Unicode` and have their own number associated with them. For instance, in text you provided, they are [0xU1E17](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/7703) and [0x1E53](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/7763) Unicode characters. Some fonts may contain such glyphs, so that there is a second option to showing base glyph and stacking diacritics: showing combined glyphs. For example, `ArialUni` shipped with Windows does contain the above mentioned glyphs.

To try this approach, you would need the following code for composing known Unicode base glyph + diacritics combinations into single glyphs:

```
String originalStr = "ḗ and ṓ are characters that display incorrectly";
String normalizedStr = java.text.Normalizer.normalize(originalStr, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
new Text(normalizedStr); // Use this normalized Text instance
```

The result that I got with `ArialUni`:
[image]

But again as I mentioned do it at your own risk because it will only work if there are necessary combinations present both in Unicode and font. For correct rendering you still should use `pdfCalligraph`.